# Jquery passing data to ajax function in mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have developed ASP.NET MVC4 File upload it is working fine but i have one problem i need   to passing parameter **Folderid**  to controller but unfortunately i cant get folderId in controller. could you please help me as soon as possible

My code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var Folderid = "ab";     

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Home/UploadFiles',
            autoUpload: true,
             data: { name: Folderid  },
            done: function (e, data) {
                if (data.result.name == '') {
                    $('.file_name').html('Please Upload valid image...');
                    $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', 0 + '%');

                }
                else {
                    $('.file_name').html("Uploaded Successfully..[ " + data.result.name + " ]");
                }

            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
    });
```

My controller code below

```
[HttpPost]
        public ContentResult UploadFiles(string name)
        {

            string FolderId = name;

            var r = new List<UploadFilesResult>();               
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".icon" };

                HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                    continue;
                if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName).ToString()))
                {
                    r.Add(new UploadFilesResult()
                    {
                        Name = "",
                        Length = 0,
                        Type = ""

                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
                    r.Add(new UploadFilesResult()
                    {
                        Name = hpf.FileName,
                        Length = hpf.ContentLength,
                        Type = hpf.ContentType
                    });
                }
            }
            return Content("{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + "\",\"type\":\"" + r[0].Type + "\",\"size\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", r[0].Length) + "\"}", "application/json");
        }
```

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934689/can-someone-explain-how-to-implement-the-jquery-file-upload-plugin Which may be of some use. Also, I'd suggest mentioning the library you're using, fileUpload is not a jQuery function.

Comment: @Swires, Could you pls specify where is my worng.. please

Comment: See answer for possible fix, but I meant that fileUpload is a seperate library https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data and should be mentioned as such in the question. When I read it first I thought 'I didn't know jQuery handled file uploads!?'

Comment: @ Swires, Got It great thanks...you have saved my lot of time i really appreciate you i have used like this  formData : {name: Folderid},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit* Perhaps try changing data to formData in the fileupload call like so:

```
formData: { name: Folderid  },
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data).

Comment: i have tried to use controller like this  but i got Null reference  error in 'Request.Form["name"]'

Comment: this is not working string FolderId = Request.Form["name"]. You have commented link is working you mentioned  this link github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/…     so if you edit answer make as this link i will tick answer