# Jquery Ajax File Upload Done Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have the following code to submit a form using jQuery Ajax:

**HTML**

```
<form id="note_form" action="upload_note.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="note_title" />
  <textarea id="note_text"></textarea>
  <input type="file" id="image" multiple="false" accept="image/*" />
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#note_form').on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this),
                url = $form.attr('action');
            var posting = $.post(url, {
                title: $("#note_title").val(),
                text: $("#note_text").val()
            });
            posting.done(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            });
     });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
//$image = $_POST['image'];
echo $title;
```

The code works fine but I have no idea on how to send the image to the server using this function.

***EDIT***

**HTML**

```
<form id="note_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="note_title" />
   <textarea name="note_text"></textarea>
   <input type="file" name="image" multiple="false" accept="image/*" />
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#note_form').on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "upload_note.php";
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: "json",
             data: formData,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
      });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$title = $_POST['note_title'];
echo $title;
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934689/can-someone-explain-how-to-implement-the-jquery-file-upload-plugin

Comment: It should be in the $_FILES array in PHP, you can use move_uploaded_file() to put it in the directory you want. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @mark.hch I'm aware of how to receive the data on the server, my problem is in sending the data on the client side only. I just can't figure it out using done function

Comment: Why do you need to use it in .done function? Can't it be in .success?

Comment: @WilliamXavier I have no preferences, can you show me how? sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Check my answer, so in your form, instead of using `id's`, you'll use the attribute `name` (E.g.: `<input name="note_text" />`, and in your PHP file you use `$_POST["note_text"]` and `$_FILES` for the uploaded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that, so you only have to set in your inputs HTML elements the attribute name, and get them with $_POST in your PHP.
This way, Ajax will send all the info from your form.

```
$('#note_form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'PATH_TO_YOUR_PHP',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:"json",
      data:formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {

                // .success stuff here

        }
    });

});
```

So in your form, instead of using `id's`, you'll use the attribute name (E.g.: `<input name="note_text" />`, and in your PHP file you use `$_POST["note_text"]` and `$_FILES` for the uploaded image.

Comment: I tried this but this is not submitting!

Comment: Can you show how you're using the code and your PHP code?

Comment: Don't forget to apply name attribute to your file input type as well, If you don't use name attribute you're not sending the image: `<input type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple="false" accept="image/*" />`

Comment: I have, check the edit please

Comment: You're trying to echo an invalid string, `$_POST['tsitle']` you have to change to `$_POST['note_title']`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I'm using   `$_POST['note_title']`

Comment: removing json has made the form to submit? Can you elaborate?

Comment: So that was the problem, at the end of your PHP file you was not encoding the PHP response as JSON, like: `echo json_encode($title)`

Comment: Thank you, should I use json then? or leave it like this?

Comment: It's not mandatory, JSON is better to work when you know how it works, that's up to you :)