# Adding ajax jQuery File upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, I have the following form for image upload:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="upload_image">
    <input id="fileupload"  type="file" name="files[]" class="files rhiu" onchange="UploadImage(event);" accept='image/*'/>
    <div id="progress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="fileList">
    <!-- The file list will be shown here -->
    </ul>   
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_UploadImage', 'UploadImage' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_UploadImage', 'UploadImage' );
function UploadImage()
{
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$files = $_FILES['files'];
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
    ...ADDING IMAGE TO A POST...
    } 
} 
echo json_encode($image_path);
exit;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function UploadImage(e)
{
  var form = document.forms.namedItem("upload_image"); 
  var formdata = new FormData(form); 
  formdata.append('action', 'UploadImage');
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: upload_image.ajax_url, 
    data: formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {                   
      alert('Success');
    }       
  });
}
```

As of these, everything works fine.

But I am trying to implement Bluimp jQuery File upload as the uploading handler following the chosen answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934689/can-someone-explain-how-to-implement-the-jquery-file-upload-plugin).

I am having a hard time to use the [ajax option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#ajax-options).

**So here is what I am trying to do:**

1. using the blueimp jQuery file upload to upload images.
2. The data are added via ajax function ("UploadImage").

What change do I need to make in the js to include the plugin?

**What I tried:**

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("upload_video"); 
var formdata = new FormData(form); 
formdata.append('action', 'UploadImage');
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: upload_image.ajax_url, 
  data: formdata,
  add: function (e, data) {
    var tpl = $('<li class="working">'+
      '<input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48" data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" />'+
        '<p></p><span></span></li>' );
    tpl.find('p')
      .text(data.files[0].name)
      .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');
    data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);
    tpl.find('span')
      .click(function() {
        if (tpl.hasClass('working')) {
          jqXHR.abort();
        }
        tpl.fadeOut(function(){
          tpl.remove();
        });
      });
    var jqXHR = data.submit();
  },
  progressall: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first thing I noticed is in HTML

```
Need to make form multi-part for image uploading
```