# jQuery File Upload Basic Plus Ui and i18n

Tags: internationalization, jquery-file-upload

I use  jQuery File Upload Basic Plus Ui for a multiple upload files. I need to display error messages in multiples languages (English, French and Spanish) but I don’t know how to create

```
messages: {
      maxNumberOfFiles: 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
      acceptFileTypes: 'File type not allowed'
      maxFileSize: 'File is too large',
      minFileSize: 'File is too smal
}
```

in multiple languages and  how to declare the language for

```
file.error = settings.i18n('acceptFileTypes');
```

With the demo version, the errors messages are displayed ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to instanciate fileupload plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
     url: 'yoururl',
     acceptFileTypes: exttensionsRegex, 
     maxFileSize: yourmaxsize ,
     maxTotalFileSize: totalsize, 
     maxNumberOfFiles: numberoffiles , 
     messages: {
        maxNumberOfFiles: 'yourText',   
        acceptFileTypes: 'yourText' ,   
        maxFileSize:  'yourText',
        minFileSize:  'yourText'
     }
  });
});
```

If this javascript is generated by your server side code, then you can use the internationalization API to get the right messages and put them in place of `yourText`

As for :

```
file.error = settings.i18n('acceptFileTypes');
```

Actually  you don't need to do anything, let it how it is and it would work.

I hope it can help